# Query composition over LINQ Entity-Framework

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a query that i compose it from some options, like this

```
string q1 ="SELEC * from MyTable";
string q2 =string .Empty;

if(options1)
 q2+=" Condition_1 ";
if(options2)
 q2+=" Condition_2";
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(q2))
 q1+=" WHERE"+q2; 

cmd.Execute(...
```

How can i do that against LINQ over entity-framework-6 in just one attempt?

Comment: You can check the condition with a ternary operator something like `from t in myTable where  Options1 ? FieldtoCompare : -1 equals Options1 ? "Condition_1" : 0 and Options2 ? FieldtoCompare : -1 equals Options2 ? "Condition_2" : 0`

Comment: @Nilesh but sometime the composition  has multiple tables, i have some big composition over multiple tables, required table is present only if options need it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by working with a IQueryAble.
This example may help you :

```
//Define your query without executing it.                  
IQueryable<YourEntityType> query= (from s in Context.MyTable select s);

if(options1)
//Add a where clause to your IQueryable
  query= query.Where(p=> p.SomeProperty == "Something");

if(options2)
//Add another where clause to your IQueryable
 query= query.Where(p=> p.SomeProperty == "Something else");

//Executes the query depending your options.
var Result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: What you mean is, i can compose by linq without run the query, after all, i will run one and only one  link query by calling ToList or ..., thank you

Comment: yes, the query won't be run until you call .toList(), .AsEnumerable() or anything else retrieving you rows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can chain several .Where operations. So you can write smt like

```
    var set = MySet;
    if (cond_1) {
      set  = set.Where(a=>...);
    }
    if (cond_2) {
      set  = set.Where(a=>...);
    }
    set.ToList()
```

etc